# Autoplay embedded Twitter video

Tags: javascript, twitter

Is it possible to autoplay embedded Twitter videos? The code generates iframe which prevents me from using some javascript click tricks I know of, but is there a way to autoplay it?

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/krQBSopqZh7AG5BiRLYe?p=preview)

```
<script>window.twttr = (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
    t = window.twttr || {};
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return t;
  js = d.createElement(s);
  js.id = id;
  js.src = "https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);

  t._e = [];
  t.ready = function(f) {
    t._e.push(f);
  };

  return t;
}(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));
</script>

<blockquote class="twitter-video" data-status="hidden" lang="en">
<a href="https://twitter.com/twitter/status/560070183650213889"></a>
</blockquote>
```

Comment: Were you able to achieve autoplay on embedded video?

Comment: No I couldn't get it to work. Haven't tried recently thou. Maybe it is possible nowadays.

Answer (score -3):

Use this below link for a reference, Hope you find the right way to enable autoplay functionality.

https://blog.twitter.com/2015/introducing-autoplay-video-and-a-new-standard-for-viewability

or

http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-video-autoplay-on-twitter/

Comment: These have nothing to do with embedded videos.